# Get the current week number in month from Date

Tags: swift

I am currently facing a weird issue. I am trying to find out in which week of a month a given `Date` instance lies.

My code is the following:

```
var calendar : Calendar {
    var calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
    calendar.timeZone = .UTC

    return calendar
}


func generateDate(year: Int, month: Int, day: Int) -> Date {
    let dateComponents = DateComponents(year: year, month: month, day: day)
    return calendar.date(from: dateComponents)!
}

print(calendar.component(.weekOfMonth, from: Date.generateDate(year: 2019, month: 12, day: 1))) // prints "0"
print(calendar.component(.weekOfMonth, from: Date.generateDate(year: 2020, month: 1, day: 1))) // prints "1"
```

`generateDate` simply generates a Date with the help of `calendar`. When I print the both statements I get `0` and `1` as the result. In my opinion this is wrong. I would assume I get the same value for both since both dates should be in the first week of their respective month value.

Another example would be the 2. Dec 2019, this should give the second week as well as the 6. January 2020 should also give me the second week.

Does anyone know what could be wrong here or where my mistake could be ?

Comment: Why is 2 Dec 2019 in the second week of december?

Comment: @koen I hope I am not completely lost right now, but the 1 Dec 2019 is a Sunday and I assume the week starts at Monday, therefore the 2 Dec 2019 is in the second week of December

Comment: You can set the first weekday to Monday using `calendar.firstWeekday = 2`.

Comment: As far as I am aware of Monday is the first day of the week according to  ISO 8601. Therefore `calendar.firstWeekDay ` appears to be already set to `2`

Comment: Why are you using UTC timeZone? And why are you using ISO8601 calendar? Using the current calendar and the current timeZone I get 1 for both dates.

Comment: `extension Date {
    init(year: Int, month: Int, day: Int, calendar: Calendar = .current, timeZone: TimeZone = .current) {
        self.init(timeInterval: 0, since: DateComponents(calendar: calendar, timeZone: timeZone, year: year, month: month, day: day).date!)
    }
    var weekOfMonth: Int { Calendar.current.component(.weekOfMonth, from: self) }
}`
`Date(year: 2019, month: 12, day: 1).weekOfMonth  // 1`
`Date(year: 2020, month: 1, day: 1).weekOfMonth   // 1`

Comment: @LeoDabus My idea is to create UTC dates and use ISO8601 since with this calendar the week is starting Mondays. Thanks a lot also for your code, but unfortunately it is returning `1` for the 2. Dec 2019 as well but the 2. Dec is already in week 2 of December

Comment: @grahan: did you try `firstWeekday` as I suggested above?

Comment: @koen `calendar.firstWeekday` is a `get only` variable so I cannot set it unfortunately. But if I am using the iso calendar it is already set to `2` so I guess this is fine

Comment: Hmm, according to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2293656-firstweekday it’s both get and set.

Comment: @koen I just retried.. sorry for the confusion, you are right I can set it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the 1st day of the month falling on a sunday, try march 01, 2020 if you want confirmation.

The first week of the month is chosen by Swift according to their own standards as ISO standards do not suggest any specific implementations so the Swift team went with this. You can ask them in their forums what their reasoning behind this is [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#Weeks_per_month)

Comment: So basically whenever a month starts on a Sunday the weekOfMonth returns 0 else 1 ?

Comment: I agree with Jokaim. It depends on the locale

Comment: Thank you both Abishek and Joakim. You helped me in creating my own solution for the problem. For now I stick with the iso8601 calendar and created a custom solution for handling the week 0 issue

Answer (score 1):

The logic for `.weekOfMonth` seems to be that if the "first" week is less than half a week, that is 3 days, then it is considered to be week 0 and otherwise week 1. But note that this is dependent on what locale is being used, for a country like Canada that has Sunday as first day of week there is never a week 0 when running the below code. So when the first day of week is Monday `.weekOfMonth` will return a value between 0 and 5 but when it is Sunday the range is 1 to 6.

This can be seen running the following code in a playground

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let year = 2019

print("First day of week: \(calendar.weekdaySymbols[calendar.firstWeekday - 1])")

for month in 1...12 {
    print(calendar.monthSymbols[month - 1])
    let first = calendar.date(from: DateComponents(year: year, month: month, day: 1))!
    if let range = calendar.range(of: .day, in: .month, for: first) {
        var currentWeek = -1
        for day in range {
            let date = calendar.date(from: DateComponents(year: year, month: month, day: day))!
            let week = calendar.component(.weekOfMonth, from: date)
            if week > currentWeek {
                currentWeek = week
                let dayOfWeek = calendar.component(.weekday, from: date)
                print("Week# \(week), weekday \(calendar.weekdaySymbols[dayOfWeek - 1])")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to me if you want whatever day it is on the 1st to be the first day of weekOfMonth = 1 then you need to write your own code for this

Comment: You are right, when I use `Calendar.current` there is never a week 0, but with the `.iso8601` calendar there can be a week 0